# A change in a Unity RGB emission colour only shows when it reaches 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rgb

So after a fair bit of googling, I've come up with a bit of a script to change the emission of a material (a little reactor thing on the side of the weapon) depending on the amount of ammo left in the weapon so that it can sort of serve as an indicator.

The only issue with it is that the emission colour only changes visibly when it reaches 0.

I've played around a little bit with it, but due to my inexperience with C# (I'm more or less a newbie to it) I'm not sure what the issue is.

This is my code with a fair bit cut out so it just removes ammo each update instead of when the weapon shoots (ammo is set to 51 by default by the way for ease of colour change):

```cs
   public Material reactor;

   public float ammo;

   Vector4 emit = new Color(0f, 255f, 0f, 1f);

   public void Update() {

     Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer> ();

     reactor.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", emit);

     if (ammo >= 1) {

       ammo--;
       float emitchange = emit.y - 5f;
       emit = new Vector4(emit.x, emitchange, emit.z, emit.w);

       reactor.SetColor("_EmissionColor", emit);

     } else {

       Debug.Log("Ammo Empty");

     }
   }
```

For some reason, it just refuses to show any change in the emission until emit.y reaches 0, meaning that I don't get the effect I want from it.

I hope someone knows what to do, thanks!

*(I also posted this to Unity Answers but it's been in moderation for the past 24 hours so I thought I'd take to here, where answers come much easier apparently)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are used [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html), which components are floats in range from 0.0 to 1.0.

But youo operate it as a [Color32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html), which components are integers in range from 0 to 255.

While these two can be implictly converted into each other, to get it work, you only need to change "Color" in this line:

```
Vector4 emit = new Color(0f, 255f, 0f, 1f);
```

...to "Color32".

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket! There were a few things I had to change around (I managed to get the values in the Color32 so wrong that it just went through a rainbow spectrum and then turned black) but I got it working in the end. Thanks so much for your help!